# Rspec what is wrong with my test for create controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

I am trying to learn TDD and this is part of my homework I couldn't figure out how to do it.

I want to test `create` controller action, and here is my code for test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MoviesController do
  describe 'create' do
    it 'should call the model method perform create!' do
      Movie.should_receive(:create!).with({"title" => 'Milk', "rating" => 'R'})
      post :create, :movie => {:title => 'Milk', :rating => 'R'}
    end
  end
end
```

But I got:

```
Failures:

  1) MoviesController create should call the model method performe create!
     Failure/Error: post :create, :movie => {:title => 'Milk', :rating => 'R'}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:50:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.21714 seconds
```

And here is create action I am testing against. Yes, it is TDD, and yes, I am testing a
working code, and it is the testing doesn't working :D

```
 def create
    @movie = Movie.create!(params[:movie])
    flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} was successfully created."
    redirect_to movies_path
 end
```

I don't even know why I got the undefined method error message? I have a few other test passed but I deleted in this code snippe for simplicity, so I don't think it is related db/model related config problem. But why it does not working and how to change it?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a should_receive like that, it will return nil so the next line (when setting the flash message) attempts to retrieve the title from nil.  Change your should_receive to:

```
  Movie.should_receive(:create!).with({"title" => 'Milk', "rating" => 'R'}).and_return(stub_model(Movie))
```

Comment: Should_receive will return nil, even though it did received the matching parameter "{"title" => 'Milk', "rating" => 'R'}" so I need catch the return value, did I got it right?

Comment: Sorry, I got it now, it come from the controller line. Thank you @ctide, saved my day!